# javascript append() function breaks a slider

Tags: javascript, slider, append, swiper.js

i have this code:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

The slider works perfectly. 
But if i use something like this in my javascript:

```
    var output = $('.swiper-wrapper');          
    var landmark = '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide1</div>';            
    output.append(landmark);
```

And then edit the slide code as the following:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<!-- append here -->
</div>
<!-- Add Pagination -->
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
<!-- Add Arrows -->
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
```

it's appended correctly but the slide does NOT work anymore. How is it possible?

EDIT: i see everytime i use append() function, something breaks. Even an ul list . It's like...when i use this method, it doesn't care about css...

Comment: Without knowing the library you use for the slider I would say its javascript is losing sync with the element. You can try to unbind it and rebind again, for example calling again to the `$(element).sliderOrWhatever()` after the `append`.

Comment: here is the slider: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/21-autoplay.html

Comment: EDIT: i see everytime i use append() function, something breaks. Even an ul list . It's like...when i use this method, it doesn't care about css...

Comment: Following [this](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.V1vxDKKF51M) instructions I meant the `var mySwiper = new Swiper (...)`. If you remove an element, its binding are lost. There's probably a method in Swiper to refresh. I don't understand thought what happens with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `observer` parameter to `true` when you initialize `Swiper` object. Example:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    // ...other parameters
    observer: true
});
```

That will make Swiper look for DOM changes to update itself.

Comment: it's fantastic. you rock!

Comment: Setting `observer: true` fixed the main load issue but now the bottom slide is displayed and the scroll bar does not function correctly until i inspect element on the page: https://d1nshvmz5lt3t9.cloudfront.net/

Comment: Adding `centeredSlides: true` to the options seemed to fix the starting slide problem. I have disabled the scrollbar for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can found right solution at Swiper docs (http://idangero.us/swiper/api/):

```
    mySwiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10"</div>')
    mySwiper.appendSlide([
       '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10"</div>', 
       '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11"</div>'
    ]);
```